# IEnumerable<T> и оператор foreach()

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

Я реализовал простенький односвязный список сначало так :

Клас, производный от интерфейса `IEnumerable<T>`

```
class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public Goods<T> head;
    public Goods<T> tail;
    //add,remove и так далее
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Goods<T> curr = head;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            yield return curr.Item;
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Затем его переписал его так, что бы он не был производным от интерфейса `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
class MyList<T> 
{
    public Goods<T> head;
    public Goods<T> tail;
    //add,remove и так далее
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Goods<T> curr = head;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            yield return curr.Item;
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
   }
}
```

На MDSN написано :

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the IEnumerable or IEnumerable interface.

Второй класс не является производным от IEnumerable. Каким образом я тогда могу спокойно по нему пройтись оператором foreach()?

```
MyList<int> myList = new MyList<int>();
myList.Add(10);
myList.Add(20);
foreach(var c in myList)
{
 Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: потому что foreach пытается вызвать метод `GetEnumerator`

Comment: @Grundy Что значит "пытается"? Он его определенно вызовет, если код скомпилировался.

Comment: @Igor, если он есть :-)

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю, оператор foreach() метод GetEnumerator рефлексией ищет?

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000, нет, он вызывает его напрямую: `callvirt    UserQuery+MyList<System.Int32>.GetEnumerator`

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000, рефлексия тут не нужна, т.к. это происходит во время компиляции, компилятор ищет подходящий метод и делает его вызов

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Открываем [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) и читаем:

> Оператор `foreach` выполняет оператор или блок операторов для каждого элемента в экземпляре типа, который реализует интерфейс `System.Collections.IEnumerable` или `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. Оператор `foreach` не ограничивается этими типами. Он может применяться к экземпляру любого типа, который удовлетворяет следующим условиям:
>
> - включает открытый метод `GetEnumerator` без параметров со следующим типом возвращаемого значения: класс, структура или тип интерфейса;
> - тип возвращаемого значения метода `GetEnumerator` должен содержать открытое свойство `Current` и открытый метод `MoveNext` без параметров с типом возвращаемого значения `Boolean`.

---

Таким образом, достаточно просто наличия подходящего метода `GetEnumerator`.

---

[Спецификация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement) уточняет, что вот такой `foreach`

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded_statement
```

на этапе компиляции раскрывается в

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded_statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

(`C` — тип коллекции, `E` — тип энумератора, `V` — тип значения элемента коллекции.) [Таким образом, всё происходит на этапе компиляции, рефлексия не применяется.]

Comment: то есть на самом деле и IEnumerator тож не нужен :)

Comment: @Grundy: Если посмотреть в спецификацию, то он тоже играет.

Comment: Бахни дубликатором :)

Comment: @Grundy: О, точно!

Comment: @Grundy: Просто `IEnumerable<T>` наследует `IEnumerable`. Но если тип энумератора — структура, то выгоднее не идти через интерфейс, чтобы не упаковывать её.